# Error on receive POST from third party URL in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, post, devise

I receive POST request from third party URL and update the data to my DB.

In `config/environments/production.rb`, I have:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Now when I receive the request the following error was occurred in my console.

```
Started POST "/delivery_details" for 35.355.466.466 at 2015-07-20 17:11:51 +1000
    Processing by DeliveryDetailsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"data"=>"{\"numbers\":{\"911234567890\":{\"desc\":\"MESSAGE\",\"status\":1,\"userId\":\"35534\",\"senderId\":\"qwerty\",\"date\":\"2015-07-20 12:41:59.0\"}},\"requestId\":\"12345566778\"}"}
    Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
    Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 35.355.466.466 at 2015-07-20 17:11:51 +1000
    Cannot render console from 35.355.466.466! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
      Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (55.3ms)
      Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.9ms)
      Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (0.1ms)
      Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (7.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 78.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My controller:

```
class DeliveryDetailsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    updateSmsDeliveryStatus
  end

  def updateSmsDeliveryStatus    
    destinationType = "SMS"

    json = JSON.parse(params["data"])    
    requestId = json["requestId"]
    numbers = json['numbers']

    numbers.each do |num|       
      @delivery_detail = DeliveryDetail.where(sms_request_id: requestId, destination_value: num[0].to_s, 
                                                             destination_type: destinationType)
                                                      .update_all(:is_success => num[1]["status"], :sent_date => num[1]["date"])      
    end     
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have in your application controller the next line:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

So in your controller you need to skip this authentication:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

And I don´t see in your controller the action create so maybe you receive a 404 error after this